# Is there a way to know how many parameters are needed for a method?

Tags: ruby

Using `irb`, we can list methods for particular object by doing following:

```
"Name".methods
```

But if I want to know how many parameters are needed for a particular method, how can I achieve this?  I mean is there any way (by hitting some command on irb), we can get number of parameters for particular method (instead of referring to docs)?

`.methods` returns only method names, not list of parameters for method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the method [`Method#arity`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-arity):

```
"string".method(:strip).arity
# => 0
```

From the Ruby documentation:

> Returns an indication of the number of arguments accepted by a method.
>   Returns a nonnegative integer for methods that take a fixed number of
>   arguments. For Ruby methods that take a variable number of arguments,
>   returns -n-1, where n is the number of required arguments. For methods
>   written in C, returns -1 if the call takes a variable number of
>   arguments.

So, for example:

```
# Variable number of arguments, one is required
def foo(a, *b); end
method(:foo).arity
# => -2

# Variable number of arguments, none required
def bar(*a); end
method(:bar).arity
# => -1

# Accepts no argument, implemented in C
"0".method(:to_f).arity
# => 0

# Variable number of arguments (0 or 1), implemented in C
"0".method(:to_i).arity
# => -1
```

**Update** I've just discovered the exitence of [`Method#parameters`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters), it could be quite useful:

```
def foo(a, *b); end
method(:foo).parameters
# => [[:req, :a], [:rest, :b]]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `arity`

> Returns an indication of the number of arguments accepted by a method. Returns a nonnegative integer for methods that take a fixed number of arguments. For Ruby methods that take a variable number of arguments, returns -n-1, where n is the number of required arguments. For methods written in C, returns -1 if the call takes a variable number of arguments.

Example from [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-arity)

```
class C
  def one;    end
  def two(a); end
  def three(*a);  end
  def four(a, b); end
  def five(a, b, *c);    end
  def six(a, b, *c, &d); end
end

c = C.new
c.method(:one).arity     #=> 0 
c.method(:two).arity     #=> 1
c.method(:three).arity   #=> -1
c.method(:four).arity    #=> 2
c.method(:five).arity    #=> -3
c.method(:six).arity     #=> -3
```

Answer (score 3):

There is one special case when you can't use the approach defined in other answers. It's about the method `#initialize` of some class that does not yet have an instance.

If you'll try `Method#arity` for `SomeClass::new`, you'll always get -1:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(a, b)
  end
end
SomeClass.method(:new).arity # => -1
```

You need an instance of your class `SomeClass` to use `Method#arity` on it, but you can't get this instance because you yet don't know how many arguments need `SomeClass::new`.

Fortunately, this problem can be solved. Just use `instance_method(:initialize)` on `SomeClass` and you will get the desired result:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(a, b)
  end
end
SomeClass.instance_method(:initialize).arity # => 2
```

By the way, you can use this approach for any instance method of some class without creating an instance of this class. For example, the following two lines will give the same result:

```
"string".method(:strip).arity # => 0
String.instance_method(:strip).arity # => 0
```

Comment: The `initialize` method was exactly what I was looking for.