# How to get documentation for a method in a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to find out about the `can?` method used by [`cancancan`](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan) gem.

I tried [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cancancan/3.1.0), but cannot locate the method `can?`:

[image]

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17590130/5783745), I tried these:

```
can?.arity
NoMethodError: undefined method `can?' for main:Object

can?.parameters
NoMethodError: undefined method `can?' for main:Object
```

I'm simply trying to find out what parameters `can?` (the cancancan method used in the view) wants to receive, but this example is a good opportunity to learn how to do this for other methods as well, hence I hope for a general solution (one that will allow me to look up documentation for methods beyond the one asked in this specific example).

Thanks in advance for all help/pointers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to using external sites, you can try `ri` from the command line:

```
ri "can?"
```

When you install a gem, the ri documentation is (usually) installed as well. The `ri` command line tool will search installed gem documentation for methods and constants matching your input and present them.

Since it runs locally, this can be a great resource when you don't have an internet connection handy!

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a web version of the same docs? E.g. I looked up `fields_for` on the web and see [these](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) docs, which IMO are inferior to those produced via `ri "fields_for"`. It would be great to know if there's a web version of the `ri` docs?

Comment: There is! Just run `ri --server` and it'll boot up on localhost:8214.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to enter `can?` into the search bar of [the site you linked](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cancancan/3.1.0), which gives these two results:

- [`CanCan::ControllerAdditions#can?`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/cancancan/CanCan/ControllerAdditions:can%3F)
- [`CanCan::Ability#can?`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/cancancan/3.1.0/CanCan/Ability:can%3F)

Comment: CanCan and CanCanCan are not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959887/9595653

Comment: But this is from CanCanCan not CanCan.  CanCanCan is a fork of CanCan.  I guess they didn't change all the class names.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but just some tips I was told in another forum:

- Not every ruby gem method will be have documentation for every method, so don't expect to find documentation for every method for every gem
- Try finding the source code (e.g. github), and searching the particular repository for the method name with `def`  prepended all in double quotes. That is:

Go to the github repository, then go to the search bar (top left), then search like so (and select "In this repository" when searching)

[image]

That will give [these](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/search?q=%22def+can%3F%22&unscoped_q=%22def+can%3F%22) search results:

[image]

And we can see the method defined [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/6d0e62bf0c475964a0533608e7e7221be45de28c/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L74-L81):

[image]

Comment: yup this is a handy feature of github, allowing for easy cross referencing via links.

Answer (score 2):

Jörg's answer is correct, but I also wanted to show some alternate ways to find the source code for a method:

1. Use `show-source` from Pry gem:

   ```
   show-source CanCan::Ability#can?
   ```

   of course, to do this you would need to know that the method is defined on `CanCan::Ability`. To find that information out you could use `<my_record>.method(:own?).owner`.
2. Use `source-location` in Ruby core:

   You can use `<record>.method(:own?).source_location` - this will tell you the file that the method is defined in as well as the line number, so you can open it up in text editor to inspect